# Error al exportar "logistic_regression" en clasificador naive Bayes

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

En este código se pretender hacer un clasificador naybe bayes y que muestre una gráfica con los resultados.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

from logistic_regression import plot_classifier

imput_file="archivo.txt"
x=[]
y=[]

with open(input_file,'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data=[float() for x in line.split(',') ]
        x.append(data[:-1])
        y.append(data[-1])

x=np.array(x)        
y=np.array(y)

classier_gausiannb=GaussianNB()
classier_gausiannb.fit(x,y)
y_pred = classifier_gaussiannb.preddict(x)

accuracy=100.0*(y==y_pred).sum()/x.shape[0]
print("La precisión del clasificador es ", round(acuracy,2),'%')

plot_classifier(classifier_gausiannb,x,y)
plt.show()
```

El error que da es el siguiente:

> `ImportError: No module named> 'sklearn.logistic_regression'`

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate de tener el archivo `logistic_regresion` del cual vas a importar ya que lo que buscas no está definido en sklearn, acá te dejo un ejemplo de como lo usan. [enlace](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Python-Machine-Learning-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter02/logistic_regression.py)